# jQuery Need to loop through next elements based on rowspan

Tags: jquery, attr, html-table

Well, basically, I have a table set up like so, but `<td>` elements can have any number of rowspans...

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr class="tablerow0">
        <td class="tablecol_0" colspan="4">Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow1">
        <td class="tablecol_0" rowspan="2">More Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_1" colspan="3">Some More Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow2">
        <td class="tablecol_1">And Yet More Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_2">Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_3">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ok, so what I'd like to do is determine the number of rowspans which can be done like so:

```
$("td").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rowspan');
});
```

But I need to `return false` out of this each function for each rowspan greater than 1.  For example, when it finds the  element with a rowspan of 2, it should not continue onto the next  element, because the rowspan is attached to the next  element.  BUT MORE IMPORTANTLY, I need to loop through the rowspans for `<tr>` elements.

Example, if I have this table setup:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr class="tablerow0">
        <td class="tablecol_0" rowspan="2">Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_1">Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_2">Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow1">
        <td class="tablecol_1">More Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_2">Some More Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerow2">
        <td class="tablecol_1">And Yet More Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_2">Content</td>
        <td class="tablecol_3">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Than it will need to get the last `<tr>` in here with `class="tablerow2"` because the rowspan only covers `tablerow0` and `tablerow1`.

Hopefully you get what I mean, it needs to be able to loop within the `<td>` elements and only do something when the `rowspan` quantity has been exceeded for those `<tr>` elements in the table.  The rowspan can be more than 2, I'm just simplifying this for people to grasp what I'm asking here.  Also, there can be more than 1 `<td>` element with a rowspan greater than 1 so, it should be able to know this as well.  I'm thinking I will need to build an array of rowspans here, and the array length will be based on each `<td>` rowspan value.

Comment: hey can you show us any example or image related to what exactly you need and what is happening currently, read so much of text and understanding is very difficult.. different people has different point of view in understanding.

Comment: Well, in order to show you, I'd have to give you temp access to Administration of my forum, which I might be able to limit, but definitely not posting up username and password on here.  Basically, I am creating a table that can be altered based on colspans/rowspans, and the user can alter the table with button-clicks for colspans and rowspans.  Problem is, when there is more than 1 rowspan, and I increase a colspan, it adds sections to the <tr> elements that the rowspan covers, and it shouldn't because the rowspan is using this <tr> element.  So I need to determine how many rowspans...

Comment: and based on that, I need to append <td> sections to the <tr> elements that the rowspan isn't affecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
//cache the tr elements to loop through them
var $TRs = $('tr');

//this type of loop will perform quickly
for (var i = 0, len = $TRs.length; i < len; i++) {

    //check to make sure the last TR element doesn't have a TD child element with a rowspan attribute
    if (i == 0 || $TRs.eq(i - 1).children('[rowspan]').length == 0) {
        //we are on the first TR element or the previous TR element does not have a child TD element with a rowspan attribute
    }
}
```

You can also change `[rowspan]` to `[rowspan=2]` to check for a specific rowspan value.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JyQYW/

### Update

Here is a simple example of checking for more than `rowspan=2`:

```
if (i == 0 || ($TRs.eq(i - 1).children('[rowspan=2]').length == 0 && (i > 1 && $TRs.eq(i - 2).children('[rowspan=3]').length == 0)) && (i > 2 && $TRs.eq(i - 3).children('[rowspan=4]').length == 0))) {
```

The new code checks to make sure we are enough rows down and then checks if the last three rows are affecting the current one.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like exactly what I need.  Thanks soo much!  :)  Will give it a test in my environment and let you know by tomorrow, cause it's crazy late over here and need to sleep.  Have been at it for hours already...

Comment: Well, Just testing this out a bit on jsfiddle, and if you change the rowspan to `rowspan="3"` there is no change in anything.  I'm not sure this is what I want.  It should not give it a yellow background on the 3rd row if `rowspan="3"` in the 1st row and there is only 3 rows.

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple example you can mess around with.